# How to specify image paths for Commerce feeds imports on xampp?

Tags: commerce, feeds

Been banging around with Commerce feeds and think I've wrapped my head around it. One thing which has been flummoxing is how to provide the path in the CSV file to the image(s) on my xampp install.

I put the folder in xampp/htdocs/drupal/sites/default/files/poster_pics/XXX_image.jpg

Do I provide the path to the root of the site? (IE htdocs/drupal/etc?) or do I provide the entire path to the file on the local machine? (IE C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal/ rest of the path? or something more elaborate like

file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal/sites/default/files/poster_pics/ANON0060.jpg

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that something like a drupal file system paths (`public://poster_pics/name.JPG`). There actual path: `http://example.com/sites/default/files/poster_pics/name.JPG` i.e place image or file here manually.

Comment: so in my case http://localhost:8080/drupal etc?

Comment: No, It is public://...